# Find highest number from list of numbers as strings

Tags: python, max

I tried to find the max value in list .

Why does `max(['66','9','44'])` return `9`? the max value need to be `66`

Comment: it's comparing them as strings

Comment: `max(map(int, ['66', '9', '44']))`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` argument for `max`:

```
>>> max(['66','9','44'], key=int)
'66'
```

Reason being when comparing strings it compares each element in the string one by one and 9 is the highest first character.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the numbers in your list are strings, and because of it `max` is returning [*lexicographical*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20lexicographic%20or,of%20a%20totally%20ordered%20set.) highest value. You can type-cast the numbers to `int` in order to get highest numeric value:

```
>>> max(map(int, ['66','9','44']))
66
```

Or, as mentioned in [*Jab's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673507/2063361), you can use `key` param in the `max` function to change the value on which you need to perform sorting without changing the actual values in the list. For example:

```
>>> max(['66','9','44'], key=int)
'66'  # Value '66' is still preserved as string
```